# unmet dependencies: winehq-stable

Tags: wine

According to WinHQ :[Installing WineHQ packages](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`
3. `sudo apt-key add winehq.key`

Until here: everything is fine.

4. `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'`

> Output:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
> [sudo] password for XXXX:         
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> **The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages**
> ```

Suggested by other users:

1. Run Synaptic -> fix broken packages -> did not work
2. Run Synaptic -> find all wine dependencies -> delete all -> repeat installation process -> did not work

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `bionic` codename with `focal`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for Wine on the App Manager that comes default with Elementary OS

Answer (score 0):

Even if you put focal in there you get this:

```
roy@MyLaptop:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
roy@MyLaptop:~$
```